# How to read data from a 3.5mm headphone jack?

Tags: arduino, audio, analog

I was searching for a way to read data from a 3.5mm hack using an Arduino, but I couldn't find a well-detailed, beginner-friendly, tutorial on how to make this, at least how to wire everything and create a simple I/O code. Anyone know a good, beginner-friendly, tutorial about this topic?

*PS: I don't want to use a [modem like this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10331), I to learn and make it not communicate only with iOS/Android devices.*

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Input/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: That tutorial looks quite complex in my opinion...

Comment: intended for audio scope but some aspects may be useful

Comment: I was thinking about something less complex. Analyzing audio with a Arduino isn't very simple for someone that just wants to get data from a TI-84, and other devices, via a 3.5mm jack.

Comment: By definition, any translation between data and audio is a "modem". Some are simpler than others. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It seems we've come full circle -- this harkens back to the days when microcomputers stored data (and programs) on audio cassettes. Some of the same techniques used back then might apply here.

Comment: http://www.ticalc.org/pub//master.index <  you need link software for both ends and a compatible protocol in assembly language.

Comment: @Richman It can be written in BASIC, just like the one I did to create a remote shutter release for my Canon 60D.

Comment: I would not expect modem like speeds using the audio port in Basic...unless hardware based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this old question because it is too broad and unclear what is being asked - is the goal to communicate with audio-like signals, or to merely use a 3.5mm jack as a conduit for an RS232 or logic level serial stream?  That's never been established, and five years later that ambiguity continues to confuse readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Analyzing audio with a Arduino isn't very simple for someone that just
>   wants to get data from a TI-84, and other devices, via a 3.5mm jack.

If you just want to communicate with a device like a TI-84 that uses a 3.5mm jack as just a connector for some type of serial interface, this shouldn't be too hard (although most of the helpful links online are dead.)

I don't know much about the TI-84 protocol, but since you wanted a basic tutorial, I'm guessing you may need some help with Arduino serial communication. [Arduino Serial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/serial) is a great place to start, and LadyAda has a good [serial introduction](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html).

Here is an image that shows you to make the connection, (I'm not sure if any level converters are needed, but you can read the link below.)

[image]

And the code and discussion can be found here: [Arduino to TI Calculator Linking Routines](http://www.cemetech.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4771&start=0)

> PS: I don't want to use [a modem like this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10331), I to learn and make it not
>   communicate only with iOS/Android devices.

I think the board you quoted is basically a level converter, converting 3.3volt signal to 5volt arduino, and vice versa. Also it said it was a 4 conductor cable so it is different than the TI-84 cable, I believe the TI's is only a 3 conductor.

Links:

- [Video: Arduino to TI-84+ Linking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMNOGHKQDQk)
- [Video: TI-84+ to Arduino communication](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nepNMTSL09Q)
- [Slightly complex discussion](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=96301&start=0)
- [Less helpful discussion, but with code example](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=80479.0)
- A somewhat not relevant, but very cool project, [Expand TI 84+ calculator with touch screen](http://www.embedds.com/expand-ti-84-calculator-with-touch-screen/)

Comment: i have a question... what headphone wire did u use, that had the connectors in order to connect it to the arduino

Comment: @JakePaulScientist: He shows it disassembled, which makes it clear that he simply bought a plug and soldered jumper wires to it directly.

Comment: @JakePaulScientist: yeah, it was just a plug, not a cable, just the 3.5mm jack that you can buy from raidio shack. However you can use any stereo headphone cable and just cut it.